# If an assembly is in the GAC, do all assemblies that it calls have to be in the GAC too?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, assemblies, gac, dependencies

The question says it all.

Comment: Some insight here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868799/why-cant-strongly-named-assemblies-use-assemblies-that-arent-signed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An assembly in the GAC does not know about the private locations of your private assemblies. It is only aware about the GAC itself. So it can refer to the assemblies that are available in the GAC only

Comment: I see what you are saying.  But can't you hook a callback event in the GAC, and have your application DLL called that way?

Comment: @Robert: that would be a runtime dependency, not a compile-time one. It's an ambiguous question I know, but I took it to mean a compile-time dependency.

Answer (score 5):

No - the GAC is the place where you place assemblies that you specifically want to be available globally.

Comment: Correct. For example, I write ASP.NET MVC applications. The ASP.NET MVC DLL is in the GAC, but my application DLL is in the bin directory.

Comment: +1 For example all .net-classes are in the GAC and you do not have to code .net in the GAC

Comment: I think some people are missing the point of the question. If an assembly is in the GAC, do any assemblies it references also need to be present in the GAC? I would think yes.

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin, yes but you call the base class libraries, they don't call you.

Comment: So for a dll (which is in the GAC) that brings up a form (e.g. WinForm) that has 3rd party controls, don't these controls needs to be in the GAC?